# How do you route a react component from an external request?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

My navigation all works great, so when you click on the covid link it loads the component.

However.. if you load a new request using the same link in the browser such as [www.websitename.com/covid](http://www.websitename.com/covid)
then you get a 404?!

Is this a limitation of client SPA apps? surely there must be a way round this.

My setup is like the following

My main index.js

```
import React from 'react'; //react engine - no prefix so will look in npm package
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //browser support
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import './assets/css/styles.css';
import './assets/css/utility.css';
import './assets/css/animate.min.css';
import './assets/css/call-now.css';
import './assets/css/Contact-Form-Clean.css';
import './assets/css/betternav.min.css';

import App from './home-page'; 
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);    

reportWebVitals();
```

My App index.js with all the routes..

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './header.css';
import './footer.css';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';
import Body from './body';
import ClientPage from '../client-page'
import CovidPage from '../covid-page'
import Commercial from '../commercial-page'
import CarpetFloorPage from '../carpetfloor-page'
import IndustrialConstructionPage from '../industrial-construction-page';
import SafeContractorPage from '../safecontractor-page';
import ContactPage from '../contact-page';
import IndustrialCommercialPage from '../industrial-commercial-page';
//import Popper from 'popper.js';
import BetterNav from '../utility/betternav.js'

class App extends Component { 


  componentDidMount()
  {
    //BetterNav();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header></Header>
        <Switch>          
          <Route exact path='/' component={Body} />          
          <Route path='/clients' component={ClientPage} />
          <Route path='/covid' component={CovidPage} />
          <Route path='/commercial' component={Commercial} />       
          <Route path='/carpet-floor' component={CarpetFloorPage} /> 
          <Route path='/industrial-construction' component={IndustrialConstructionPage} /> 
          <Route path='/safe-contractor' component={SafeContractorPage} />          
          <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage} />
          <Route path='/industrial-commercial' component={IndustrialCommercialPage} />

                     
        </Switch>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

and my header..

```
import logo from '../assets/img/white-tiger-cleaning.png'
import { NavLink, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

//props object is meant to be a read only object

const Header = (props) =>
(
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md navigation-clean main-nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="text-center home-title">White Tiger Cleaning</h1>
                    <h6 class="text-center text-wrap">London &amp; South East Premier Commercial Cleaning Service</h6>
                </div>
            </Link>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-grow-1 justify-content-between ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <NavLink to='/' className="nav-link" exact>Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <NavLink to='/covid' className="nav-link">Covid-19</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Services</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <NavLink to='/commercial' className="dropdown-item">Commercial</NavLink>
                            <NavLink to='/carpet-floor' className="dropdown-item">Carpet &amp; Floor Cleaning</NavLink>
                            <NavLink to='/industrial-construction' className="dropdown-item">Industrial &amp; Construction</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Health &amp; Safety&nbsp;</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <NavLink to='/safe-contractor' className="dropdown-item">Safe Contractor</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Testimonials</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <NavLink to='/clients' className="dropdown-item">Clients</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <NavLink to='/contact' className="nav-link">Contact Us</NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="center-item"><img class="header-img" src={logo} alt="White Tiger Logo" /></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

);

export default Header;
```

How can I make those links work if they are loaded externally? so not only from within the app but if I just send someone a link like [www.websitename.com/covid](http://www.websitename.com/covid).
Somehow it needs to point back to the main index.html because it all loads from there.. I am not using a backend here. It is a client app.

Further to this question and the answer below it needed server side code to provide a catch all route.. I used NodeJS to do this..

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  console.log("* index.html");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your server needs configurations, here is some description from `react router` documents:

> Routers:

> At the core of every React Router application should be a router component. For web projects, `react-router-dom` provides `<BrowserRouter>` and `<HashRouter>` routers. The main difference between the two is the way they store the URL and communicate with your web server.

1. A  uses regular URL paths. These are generally the best-looking URLs, but they require your server to be configured correctly. Specifically, your web server needs to serve the same page at all URLs that are managed client-side by React Router. Create React App supports this out of the box in development, and comes with instructions on how to configure your production server as well.
2. A  stores the current location in the hash portion of the URL, so the URL looks something like http://example.com/#/your/page. Since the hash is never sent to the server, this means that no special server configuration is needed.

you can read more about it here: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components/routers

Comment: I needed server side code code to use the regular BrowserRouter. Chose NodeJS Express.